# Juntar o banco de dados com a aplicação java

Tags: java, postgresql, netbeans

Olá, fiz um trabalho da faculdade usando telas em java utilizando a ide netbeans, fiz o crud no banco de dados ,usando postgresql como banco principal, consegui finalizar e tudo, porem eu gostaria de mandar apenas o jar para o professor, no meu computador o jar funciona, mas em outro ele não encontra o banco de dados, como faço pra "carregar" o banco de dados  com a aplicação?Obg

minha conexão

```
public void Conectabd() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    conectdbd();
    CriarBd();
}

public static Connection conectdbd() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3306/bdoficina", "postgres", "diego");
        return con;
    } catch (SQLException error) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Creio que não tem como, só se estivesse utilizando um banco "portavel", como sqlite, hsqldb.

Comment: A não ser que você pague uma hospedagem do postgree, e ponha o banco na internet.

Comment: gostaria do banco local mesmo , não tem outro tipo de banco que ja integra a aplicação não?

Comment: Tem, eu citei 2 opções, mas você teria que reescrever todas as tabelas para ele.

Comment: Eu recentemente fiz uma aplicação em Delphi tendo o PostgreSQl com BD, e utilizei de um arquivo `.ini` para realizar essa conexão com o banco, assim no meu arquivo de conexão eu colocava como `host` o IP da máquina onde o banco estava salvo, outra coisa que tive que alterar foi o arquivo **pg_hba.conf** para que fosse possivel acessar o meu BD de outra máquina, mas claro que isso só irá funcionar se os computadores em questão estiverem na mesma rede no caso

Comment: @R.Santos creio que não seja esse o caso. Veja que ele vai enviar o trabalho para o professor, ele pode abrir em qualquer lugar, que não irá funcionar, a não ser que ele tenha uma hospedagem online do banco, ou configure um dns dinamico para redirecionar para o pc dele, que deverá ficar ligado o tempo todo, sem contar problemas de conexão que podem ocorrer também.

Comment: @diegofm É verdade, não havia me ligado a essa parte da questão quando fiz o comentário

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [SQLite](https://sqlite.org).

Depois de instalar o driver JDBC, você pode tentar algo do tipo:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLiteJDBC
{
  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    Connection c = null;
    try {
      // Cria conexao
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("DB aberto com sucesso");
  }
}
```

Veja também [aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm) algumas outras operações.